# PostgreSQL queries randomly takes minutes to execute

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

When running the same SELECT query multiple times (sequentially), about 10% of queries takes minutes to execute (between 3 and 20 minutes).
All others execute in about 100 ms.
When a long duration query is running, a postgreSQL process takes 100% cpu.

We're running postgreSQL v9.4 on Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie). 
A VACUUM ANALYSE is run daily on the DB.

With logging enabled at server side, we see the following entries:

Success scenario:

```
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13776-1] STATEMENT:  BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13777-1] LOG:  rewritten parse tree:
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13778-1] DETAIL:  (
        ... )
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13779-1] STATEMENT:  BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13780-1] LOG:  duration: 0.114 ms  parse <unnamed>: BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13781-1] LOG:  duration: 0.010 ms  bind <unnamed>: BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13782-1] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13783-1] LOG:  duration: 0.015 ms
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13797-1] LOG:  plan:
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13798-1] DETAIL:     {PLANNEDSTMT 
        ...
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13799-1] STATEMENT:  select 
        ... (the SELECT query)
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13800-1] LOG:  duration: 10.303 ms  bind S_21/C_24: select 
        ... (the SELECT query again)
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13801-1] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '149', $2 = '6'...(the query parameters)
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13802-1] LOG:  execute S_21/C_24: select 
        ... (the SELECT query again)
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948  ]: [13803-1] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '149', $2 = '6'...(the query parameters again)
2018-01-02 21:41:56 CET [15948]: [13804-1] LOG:  duration: 15.662 ms
```

Failed scenario (long duration query):

```
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13060-1] STATEMENT:  BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13061-1] LOG:  rewritten parse tree:
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13062-1] DETAIL:  (
        ... )
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13063-1] STATEMENT:  BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13064-1] LOG:  duration: 0.107 ms  parse <unnamed>: BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13065-1] LOG:  duration: 0.009 ms  bind <unnamed>: BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13066-1] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13067-1] LOG:  duration: 0.016 ms
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13081-1] LOG:  plan:
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13082-1] DETAIL:     {PLANNEDSTMT 
        ...
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13083-1] STATEMENT:  select 
        ... (the SELECT query)
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13084-1] LOG:  duration: 9.886 ms  bind S_20/C_27: select 
        ... (the SELECT query again)
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13085-1] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '149', $2 = '6'...(the query parameters)
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13086-1] LOG:  execute S_20/C_27: select 
    ... (the SELECT query again)
2018-01-02 21:36:55 CET [15741]: [13087-1] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '149', $2 = '6'...(the query parameters again)

**/!\--- LOOPING ABOUT 150 times ---/!\**
        2018-01-02 21:42:23 CET [15741]: [13088-1] LOG:  temporary file: path "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp15741.XX", size 9498636 (this value changes at every loop)
        2018-01-02 21:42:23 CET [15741]: [13089-1] STATEMENT:  select 
            ... (the SELECT query again)
**/!\--- END LOOP ---/!\**

2018-01-02 21:46:19 CET [15741]: [13340-1] LOG:  duration: 563668.493 ms
2018-01-02 21:46:19 CET [15741]: [13341-1] LOG:  duration: 0.026 ms  bind S_2: COMMIT
2018-01-02 21:46:19 CET [15741]: [13342-1] LOG:  execute S_2: COMMIT
2018-01-02 21:46:19 CET [15741]: [13343-1] LOG:  duration: 0.155 ms
2018-01-02 21:46:19 CET [15741]: [13344-1] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:10:23.538 user=xxx database=yyy host=127.0.0.1 port=60880
```

When looking at execution plan, we see that:
    - All OK queries have identical plan
    - All NOK (long duration) queries have identical plan
    - OK and NOK plan differs slightly:

```
        'total_cost' values (near but different values)
        ...
        {TARGETENTRY 
            :expr 
                {VAR 
                :varno 65000 ---------> differs
                :varattno 3  ---------> differs
                :vartype 20 
                :vartypmod -1 
                :varcollid 0 
                :varlevelsup 0 
                :varnoold 10  ---------> differs
                :varoattno 1 
                :location 2459 ---------> differs
                }
        ... 
        :args (...
        {PARAM | RELABELTYPE | CONST ---------> differs, always CONST for OK queries, always PARAM | RELABELTYPE for NOK queries
        ...
        }
```

Additionnal informations added:
- Autovacuum is off (scheduled every night)
- pg_stat_reset() has been run + ANALYSE (pbm remains)
- main table statistics have been increased (500), but pbm remains.

This pbm occurs in an Alfresco (5.1g) environment (using alfresco seach API), but we cannot reproduce this pbm with direct sql queries.

Does it make sense to use so much temp files for such SELECT query ?

The query:

```
select
node.id as id 
from alf_node node 
where node.type_qname_id <> 149 
AND node.store_id = 6 
AND ( 
node.id IN 
    (
    select aspect.node_id 
    from alf_node_aspects aspect 
    where aspect.qname_id IN ( 260 )
    ) 
AND node.id IN 
    (
    select PROP.node_id 
    from alf_node_properties PROP 
    where (249 = PROP.qname_id) 
        AND PROP.string_value = 'Mandats' 
    ) 
AND node.id IN 
    (
    select PROP.node_id 
    from alf_node_properties PROP 
    where (245 = PROP.qname_id) 
        AND PROP.string_value = '1' 
    ) 
AND node.id IN 
    (
    select PROP.node_id 
    from alf_node_properties PROP 
    where (247 = PROP.qname_id) 
        AND PROP.string_value = '869637' 
    ) 
AND node.id IN 
    (
    select PROP.node_id 
    from alf_node_properties PROP 
    where (248 = PROP.qname_id) 
        AND PROP.string_value = 'AGF00619' 
    )
) 
order by node.audit_modified DESC;
```

Any advise ?
Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: Maybe there is some other query locking something your SELECT requires?

Comment: What is this temp file, and why is it growing?  (for a SELECT statement ?)

Comment: So you have a prepared (dynamic?) query that you call repeatedly. Are there concurrent sessions using the same table(s)? Is autovacuum running? Do the tables (or:indexes) contain a lot of dead rows? Maybe you should add the query to your post.

Comment: What is this temp file, and why is it growing? (for a SELECT statement ?): Good question, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried?: select pg_stat_reset();

Comment: No, I thought this was done by VACCUM ANALYSE. Isn't it ?<br/>Another option is to increase statistics level on table ?